# How can I send an email to site admin and vice-versa when user returns a product using commerce_rma?

Tags: commerce

I am using the Commerce Return Merchandise Authorization module for handling returns. It is working fine .

But one thing I want that when a user returns an order using commerce_rma then a notification mail should be triggered to the site admin, and also when the admin accepts user request or declines user request a notification mail should go to the user.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Module

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events

- There are events created in rules when [Commerce RMA](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_rma) is installed such as `After creating a new return`